# how to store $(this).closest('tr') value for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and on click of a button on one of it's column, I would open a modal and save the value of `$(this).closest('tr')` for purpose of editing table data, without the need of reloading after submission of the form in the modal.

Comment: Define "save" in this context.

Comment: Can you perhaps share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example? Without any code to look at, we are talking about a really abstracted example here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can do save it in a global var if you don't refresh your page.

If your refresh your page. You can save it in your localStorage by this methode:

The methode to save it in your localStorage:

```
    localStorage.setItem("dataForModal", JSON.stringify(YourData));
```

Methode to get it back from the localStorage:

```
var YourData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataForModal"));
```